How to organize registerd models in R with mlflow?

Using aliases in mlflow is best practice and convienient to organize registered models.
But unfortunately, even the latest mlflow R Package (Version 2.14.1) does not include any methods that allow setting aliases.
Whereas in Python one can use client.set_registered_model_alias() or client.delete_registered_model_alias(), the R package only provides mlflow::mlflow-transition-model-version-stage at the moment.
The concept of stages will be depricated...

Questions

How should I deal with this situation, should I just use stages until the R package gets updated? What would be the most sensible approach here? Using tags and accepting the problem that tags are not unique?
Does anyone know if the alias related methods will be introduced into the R package anytime soon?


You seem to be asking questions only the developers of mlflow can properly answer. Try filing an issue with them: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues. Asking about "best practices" is also off topic here because that's really more of an opinion rather than a specific programming question.

I found a somewhat okeyish workaround: I just use the mlflow rest api (https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#set-registered-model-alias) from R to set the alias...
mlflowSetRegisteredModelAlias <- function(mlflowUri, modelName, alias, version) {
  # Define api request payload
  payload <- list(name = modelName,
                  alias = alias,
                  version = as.character(version))
  
  # Make the POST request
  mlflowApiEndpoint <- paste0(mlflowUri, "api/2.0/mlflow/registered-models/alias")
  response <- mlflowApiEndpoint %>%
    httr2::request() %>%
    httr2::req_body_json(payload) %>%
    httr2::req_perform()
}

For deleting an alias it would be with ad DELETE method:
 payload <- list(name = modelName, alias = alias)
  
  # Make the DELETE request
  response <-  mlflowApiEndpoint %>%
    httr2::request() %>%
    httr2::req_method("DELETE") %>%
    httr2::req_body_json(payload) %>%
    httr2::req_perform()

